# Strange behaviour of \oldstylenums

Tags: latex, beamer, overleaf

I've just copied a latex document which was a presentation, presentation I've made last year (beamer class) where I've written the date on the title slide like this :

```
\date{\oldstylenums{\today}}
```

I run the ancient document and it is still ok --> [image]

But when I run the copy it gives me that, where the month has been replaced by a musical note (?!) :[image]

More generally there seems to be a problem about displaying months, example if I write :

```
\date{\oldstylenums{1 Juillet 2021}}
```

it gives me : [image]

Is anyone aware about this funny behaviour and how to rectify it ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`oldstylenums` uses another font encoding. You can avoid the problem by only using it for numbers:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\date{\oldstylenums{30} juin \oldstylenums{2021}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Or you could use another font which uses them by default:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\date{30 juin 2021}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

---

As to why you are having this problem in the new project? Overleaf normally does not change the texlive version of existing projects, so your old project uses texlive 2019 (or older). If you start a new project it will be with the texlive version currently used by overleaf (at the moment this is the already outdated texlive 2020). However you can select the version in the menu in the left hand sidebar. If you switch back to <= 2019 in your new project, you should not see the problem (but "juin" is still not written in the correct font, see the wrong usage of italic in your screenshot)